# QFileDialog default "Files of Type" selection has changed

Tags: qt

First off, I know near nothing about qt itself, I've never developed with it, I am user only.
For a few weeks now, I'm encountering strange behaviour of my applications using qt.

When opening a file, in the file picker that opens (my research led to qt4 QFileDialog), by default the "Files of Type" selection should most often set to be "All files" or similar.

**However, for me the default "Files of Type" selection is, what I assume would normally be the item at the very bottom of the list of types.**

In Okular this is now set to "electronic book document", in VLC it's set to some "Media files (*.3g2 *.3gp ....)".
I've attached a screenshot of my file picker opened in Okular, for you to see which exact file dialog I mean.

I'm very puzzled about this, because I would've thought that the applications itself are responsible for setting the allowed types, however this change seems to be global.
Opening these applications as root also shows the same behaviour, so it doesn't seem to be tied to my user.

I'm using Arch Linux.

If anyone could hint me in the right direction as to where such configurations could be stored I would be very grateful. I've been searching through my system and did find some config files that seem to be related to qt, however, none of them included such settings. Reinstalling Okular did not fix this issue.
[image: An example of the file dialog, having a "Files of Type" selected by default, which I would not expect.]

Thanks, and please excuse my broken english and/or edit some grammar errors out. :)

Comment: I checked the Okular source code, and there is nothing there to force a specific selection in the file type. It is possible that a new Qt version was installed on your machine and that the default behaviour has changed. In that case, there is nothing you can do, except revert to a previous Qt version system wide. But that can break other applications.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and research!

Comment: However, I'd think that if a Qt update would've changed this, many more users would be hindered in their workflow, and the behaviour would be changed back very soon. It's been unchanged for me now for about 2 weeks or so, with many full upgrades done in this time.

Comment: It has now been reported as a bug in the KDE bugtracker and will be fixed when the fix gets merged in the next version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in a recent QT update. It was only a small amount of people affected, because you had to have a specific combination of QT, Okular and X.

Comment: link to release notes / changelog / issue ticket would be nice.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).